# Unable to locate in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been searching for this in the boostrap.css for hours with no luck.  The search boxes for type, location and sort are too small and I want to make them larger.  Anyone know where I can change this is the css.  How do you go about finding it in the css, is there a way to do it with Google's inspect elements?  Thanks

This is the fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/omab/kShpU/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/omab/kShpU/2/)

I was looking in this area of the code.

```
 <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="text-muted">Type</span>
                    <strong class="selection">All</strong>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu js-select-menu js-filter">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-filter="all">All</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".type-hotel">Hotels</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".type-lodge">Lodges</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".type-motel">Motels</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: have you checked the Navbar component properties ?

Comment: have you tried FireBug or Inspector in Chrome/Opera, you will find it in seconds

Comment: I tried to locate it in Chrome but couldnt' figure it out.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a Navbar component property.  I've tried searching for .btn-group and don't see any width settings for that in the bootstrap.css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just target their classes and add a `width`:

```
.btn-group{
   width: 49%;
}

.btn-group .btn-group{
   width: 50%;
}

.btn-group .btn-group button, .btn-group button{
   width: 100%;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kShpU/4/)

Comment: I think he should find CSS components in bootstrap framework, overidding isn't the ideal solution

Comment: changing stuff in bootstrap can effect it in other places that he/she may not want. They should probably add a class or duplicate the code under a different class name

Comment: the whole bootstrap framework is made to integrate both CSS an JS , I wouldn't rename selectors either ...

Comment: im not saying rename them (that was a 3rd - last result - option), my first suggestion is to add a class and override them. That way you dont effect the original classes, their purpose, and if they are being used anywhere else throughout the codebase.

Comment: unless he-she is using a CDN to deliver CSS the best solution is to find where the selector gets defined